# Sharing records through apex with Public Group

Tags: apex, apex-sharing

[image: Opportunity Shared]I am sharing Opportunity records through OpportunityShare from Apex with Public Groups. When i checked the sharing button the record is being shared with that Group but after logging in as that user he is not able to view the Opportunity.(Checked the permission of user on profile level he is having Create,Read & Write permissions).Only on List view the Opportunity is Visible.

Code by which i am sharing the record to Public groups.Its not complete code its part of the code.

```
Public void forwardProcess(){
    Id oppId = '0069D000001rkq6QAA';
    Id groupId;
    Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity();
    try{
    groupId = [SELECT id FROM Group where DeveloperName  =: selectedApprovalLayer][0].Id;
        oppty = [SELECT Reason__c FROM Opportunity where id =: oppId][0];
    system.debug('groupId '+groupId);
  OpportunityShare oppShare = new OpportunityShare(OpportunityId = oppId,UserOrGroupId = groupId,OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit');
        if(oppty != null){
         oppty.Reason__c = Reason;   
           Update oppty; 

        }
  if(oppShare != null){
   insert oppShare;
   returnMsg = 'Success';

  }
    }
```

**Note:the standard view of Opportunity is overridden by VF page and user even has access to that VF page.As by manual sharing he is able to open the opportunity.**

[image: Insufficient Privileges Error]

> I tried to manually share the record with that user and he is able to
>   Open the Opportunity.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Is this code running inside an exception handler?

Comment: Yes i wrote inside try catch.

Comment: And is your catch block swallowing or otherwise silently suppressing exceptions?

Comment: It is not  throwing any exceptions..

Comment: Please check my updated answer for the screenshot.

Comment: How do you know it is not throwing exceptions? What does your `catch` block do?

Comment: Because i am having debug in catch which will print if there are any exceptions.

Comment: And what exception can occur here..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90425/discussion-between-deepak-agarwal-and-david-reed).